# Highcharts - Radial (or Circular) Bar Chart - Rounded Corners / Border Radius?

Tags: highcharts

I'm attempting to get rounded columns / border radius on a polar chart with Highcharts.
I've tried a number of `borderRadius` options (`plotOptions: { column: { borderRadius: 50 }}`) as well as the third-party `rounded-corners.js` script that surfaces when searching for individual rounded corners.

It seems that these options work for a regular `'column'` type chart, but once you go `polar: true`, the border radii no longer apply.

Looking for options...

Comment: Hi @MAckerman, A column in a polar chart is `path` not `rect` element, so there is no easy way to apply border radius. You can report feature request here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. It looks like Activity Gauge / solidgauge type chart will actually work out for my use case.